# I need to define two variables returning from database in a single define function in php

Tags: php, database

I have the below code:

```
define('DB_USERTABLE_NAME','firstname');
```

But i need to have `firstname` + `lastname` as `DB_USERTABLE_NAME`

Can anyone please let me know how to do it

Thanks

Regards

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: i mean i need to do something like this define('DB_USERTABLE_NAME','firstname' + 'lastname');

Comment: So why not just turn them into variables and do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
define('DB_USERTABLE_NAME',trim($firstname).trim($lastname));
```

### Example:

```
$firstname = "Rashid";
$lastname = "Rana";

define('DB_USERTABLE_NAME',trim($firstname).trim($lastname)); 

echo DB_USERTABLE_NAME; // RashidRana
```